# Can we use Realm in React Native project with Expo?

Tags: react-native, realm, expo

I am making a Mobile app in React Native with Expo.
Now I am thinking that I will use Realm to manage state in my project.

However, I am not sure that I can use Realm on Expo or not.
Expo is quite useful to create React Native Mobile Apps easily and quickly, but sometimes there are some conflict with some modules and libraries.

So, could you teach me that Realm can work on Expo or not?

Thank you,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Update 24 Jan 2022

The feature request was marked as **Complete** today.

> I can confirm that Realm works with [custom dev clients](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-42-579aee2348b6).
>
> Here is an [expo/example](https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-realm) you can use to get started today --courtesy of the Realm team.
>
> We won't be adding Realm to the Expo Go app (that you download from the App Store or Google Play Store) since we are limiting the amount of native third-party services that we include by default.

---

## Update 2 July 2021

The feature request has been marked it as *In Progress* by the Expo team.

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/realm

It should be included as part of a custom development client, you can read more about custom development clients here  https://blog.expo.dev/introducing-custom-development-clients-5a2c79a9ddf8

---

## Previous answer

From the realm docs

> Expo does not support Realm
> Unfortunately, Expo does not support Realm. If you use the Expo CLI or create-react-native-app to create your React Native project, you will need to "eject" your Expo project to use Realm. The installation steps on this page do not use the Expo CLI.

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/install/

It has been a feature request for expo since 2017 https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-for-realm

Comment: Thank you for your comment and infomation about my question!

Comment: It is now in progress, and probably even possible right away. Check that link.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, Expo now works with realm.

[Expo Announcement](https://cdn.mc-weblink.sg-mktg.com/weblink/MTY0Njk1Mjc3MnxocXFSenlVUUdNN2dhXzVKTTl4aThFZVdDY3p0ZGQwNlcwMWxtanZuMTdaMFhvcEFlN25iQTNqU1VrMGZNbGhIbThNd09KZjZvUndKMW8tSmVjY0Jzbm1ONmptMHJkRHA5a0o4TW5OamF1LWRtVHBLS1RqWGhPeFZVck5wQ1EydDl5M19GTWc1NkQ4cExlZWZRdlRyMmJYWjU3Sm1tZUZrcHJEd2tReHVzSnNKUWFIQ0hvNzI0UkQ2b2lBOVdkV0JxdkFRcDhsSmJqbWt3Z1NoYkk3OU5xMmZfWXFuQTdwSXFPSkxZVEV3WldEdks0VFJaYTlVQXQ5Qko5R1gweXVXWnh1Z2hnSU5iNzRUdmJ6Y3JwajM4cDd4eGl4V2tROWg1eHVSSTZGbVNlVjJ0UmpqUHlFaEVQb09vNmd2WUFrenpXazRfLVFXdmdaRVh5QWx8quU3g6Pp7oz2ThbAvy9q-hW8fDfI1OeBl74r-VbxXiU=)
[Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/using-expo-realm-expo-dev-client/)